# Return JSON properties

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties, key

I am trying to return my JSON object's properties. My JSON file object looks like:

```
{ Products: 
   { 
     'Cars': { tableFields: [Object] },
     'Planes': { tableFields: [Object] } 
   } 
}
```

I am trying to return an array that contains `Products'` attributes - `Cars` and `Planes`. For example - I want the end result to be the following array:

`['Cars', 'Planes']`

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function:

```
var data = {
    Products: {
        'Cars': {
            tableFields: [ Object ]
        },
        'Planes': {
            tableFields: [ Object ]
        }
    }
};

var result = Object.keys(data.Products);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keys = [];
for ( var key in Products )
{
    //We only want the direct properties
    if ( Products.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) keys[ keys.length ] = key;
}
```